# Изменить значение cookie по второму клику

Tags: javascript, cookie

Как изменить значение cookie по второму клику по элементу?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="quickOrder" name="quickOrder">
```

JS:

```
$('#quickOrder').on('click', function() {
    if (!$('.panel-hidden').hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('.panel-hidden').addClass('hidden');
        Cookies.set('panelHidden', true);
    } else {
        $('.panel-hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        Cookies.set('panelHidden', false);
    }
});
```

Первая часть работает но вторая нет.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Код `Cookies.set` добавьте в вопрос. Да и html элемента с классом `.panel-hidden`

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы просите!? это все что есть

Comment: У вас вот это библиотека подключена? `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js`

Comment: естественно подключена!